# Getting Handsake error in Spring WebClient for HTTPS site

Tags: java, spring, ssl, ssl-certificate, spring-webclient

I am trying to call site with `https` protocol using Spring `WebClient` using following code.

```
object ClientFactory {

    @Throws(
        NoSuchAlgorithmException::class,
        IOException::class,
        KeyStoreException::class,
        CertificateException::class,
        UnrecoverableKeyException::class
    )
    @JvmStatic
    fun getClient(
        trustStoreLocation: String,
        trustStorePassword: String,
        keyStoreLocation: String,
        keyStorePassword: String
    ): WebClient.Builder {
        if (trustStorePassword.isBlank() || trustStoreLocation.isBlank()) {
            return WebClient.builder()
        }

        val contextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient()

        val trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
        trustStore.load(FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStoreLocation)), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())

        val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore)
        contextBuilder.trustManager(trustManagerFactory)

        if (keyStoreLocation.isNotBlank() && keyStorePassword.isNotBlank()) {
            val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
            keyStore.load(FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStoreLocation)), keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
            val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
            contextBuilder.keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
        }

        val context = contextBuilder.build()

        return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(
                ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                    HttpClient.create().secure {
                        it.sslContext(context)
                    }
                )
            )
    }
}

val client = ClientFactory.getClient("truststore.location", "truststore.password", "keystore.location", "keystore.password").build()

client.get().uri("https://some-service").retrieve().toEntity(clazz).awaitSingleOrNull()
```

But I am getting this error.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.688 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.688 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.689 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.689 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.690 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.690 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.691 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.691 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.692 UTC|null:-1|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA for TLSv1.3
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.693 UTC|null:-1|Unable to indicate server name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.694 UTC|null:-1|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|INFO|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.694 UTC|null:-1|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.695 UTC|null:-1|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.695 UTC|null:-1|Stateless resumption supported
javax.net.ssl|ALL|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.696 UTC|null:-1|Ignore disabled signature scheme: rsa_md5
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.697 UTC|null:-1|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.701 UTC|null:-1|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.702 UTC|null:-1|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.704 UTC|null:-1|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "9DFA460AFA7E191DE2C3B11C032F1EE7435A0095D7A50EEAE3314D8C40AD44CF",
  "session id"          : "D5858682374BC479D6E926A9B8A08F5CC0D0E8A800BD19219733FC15765C2BF7",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 34 8F 95 6C E7 41 7E 7A   F0 D3 B4 BC 2E 18 CA A7  4..l.A.z........
            0010: 21 7D 8F 4C CE 5A A9 63   F2 93 D3 CA C2 E2 FE 04  !..L.Z.c........
          }
        },
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 FC E1 E7 6A 86 69 20   B0 21 40 28 9F 4F C9 8A  ....j.i .!@(.O..
            0010: 43 0E A9 31 FB A1 8B 26   F8 5F CC F3 BC D5 34 AC  C..1...&._....4.
            0020: E3 F6 92 B4 8C C9 3E 8C   04 94 2E D4 D3 A5 EF 0D  ......>.........
            0030: 7D 44 90 BE AB 90 89 B3   6A E9 F3 BF 6B D8 E0 EC  .D......j...k...
            0040: 71 
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.704 UTC|null:-1|WRITE: TLSv1.3 handshake, length = 388
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.706 UTC|null:-1|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 01 84 01 00 01   80 03 03 9D FA 46 0A FA  .............F..
  0010: 7E 19 1D E2 C3 B1 1C 03   2F 1E E7 43 5A 00 95 D7  ......../..CZ...
  0020: A5 0E EA E3 31 4D 8C 40   AD 44 CF 20 D5 85 86 82  ....1M.@.D. ....
  0030: 37 4B C4 79 D6 E9 26 A9   B8 A0 8F 5C C0 D0 E8 A8  7K.y..&....\....
  0040: 00 BD 19 21 97 33 FC 15   76 5C 2B F7 00 16 C0 2C  ...!.3..v\+....,
  0050: C0 2B C0 2F C0 30 C0 13   C0 14 00 9C 00 2F 00 35  .+./.0......./.5
  0060: 13 01 13 02 01 00 01 21   00 05 00 05 01 00 00 00  .......!........
  0070: 00 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   1D 00 17 00 18 00 19 00  ................
  0080: 1E 01 00 01 01 01 02 01   03 01 04 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
  0090: 00 00 11 00 09 00 07 02   00 04 00 00 00 00 00 17  ................
  00A0: 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 0D   00 2C 00 2A 04 03 05 03  ...#.....,.*....
  00B0: 06 03 08 07 08 08 08 04   08 05 08 06 08 09 08 0A  ................
  00C0: 08 0B 04 01 05 01 06 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
  00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02 00 2B   00 05 04 03 04 03 03 00  .......+........
  00E0: 2D 00 02 01 01 00 32 00   2C 00 2A 04 03 05 03 06  -.....2.,.*.....
  00F0: 03 08 07 08 08 08 04 08   05 08 06 08 09 08 0A 08  ................
  0100: 0B 04 01 05 01 06 01 04   02 03 03 03 01 03 02 02  ................
  0110: 03 02 01 02 02 00 33 00   6B 00 69 00 1D 00 20 34  ......3.k.i... 4
  0120: 8F 95 6C E7 41 7E 7A F0   D3 B4 BC 2E 18 CA A7 21  ..l.A.z........!
  0130: 7D 8F 4C CE 5A A9 63 F2   93 D3 CA C2 E2 FE 04 00  ..L.Z.c.........
  0140: 17 00 41 04 FC E1 E7 6A   86 69 20 B0 21 40 28 9F  ..A....j.i .!@(.
  0150: 4F C9 8A 43 0E A9 31 FB   A1 8B 26 F8 5F CC F3 BC  O..C..1...&._...
  0160: D5 34 AC E3 F6 92 B4 8C   C9 3E 8C 04 94 2E D4 D3  .4.......>......
  0170: A5 EF 0D 7D 44 90 BE AB   90 89 B3 6A E9 F3 BF 6B  ....D......j...k
  0180: D8 E0 EC 71 FF 01 00 01   00                       ...q.....
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.713 UTC|null:-1|Raw read (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.713 UTC|null:-1|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.714 UTC|null:-1|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.716 UTC|null:-1|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:296)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1343)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285)
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:519)
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:458)
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
  at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
  at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499)
  at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|61|reactor-http-epoll-2|2022-11-14 14:10:57.716 UTC|null:-1|Invalidated session:  Session(1668435057686|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)
2022-11-14 14:10:57.724 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [7b30e4fb-2]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/api/subjects/connect-status-value/versions"

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ? Request to GET https://schema-registry:8081/subjects/connect-status-value/versions [DefaultWebClient]
*__checkpoint ? Handler com.ideasbucket.tansen.controller.api.SubjectController#getVersionsBySubject(String, Continuation) [DispatcherHandler]
*__checkpoint ? org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ? HTTP GET "/api/subjects/connect-status-value/versions" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4455) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:415) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:537) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:343) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:307) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:204) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:454) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:147) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:850) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:400) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:368) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1260) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1241) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:519) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:458) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:296) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1343) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:519) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:458) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

2022-11-14 14:10:57.729  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [2d537e20, L:/172.30.0.9:50936 - R:schema-registry/172.30.0.4:8081] The connection observed an error

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

2022-11-14 14:10:57.731  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [2d537e20, L:/172.30.0.9:50936 ! R:schema-registry/172.30.0.4:8081] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:458) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

But I am unable to pinpoint the real cause of the exception. Is there anything that I am missing from `WebClient` config side.

Comment: Are you connecting to uri `https://broker` or `http://localhost` otherwise could be hostname verification failure

Comment: I am getting error for this call `https://schema-registry:8081/subjects/connect-status-value/versions`

Comment: Looks like you are not having valid server certificates in your truststore. Can you please cross check

Comment: Run `curl -vI https://schema-registry:8081/subjects/connect-status-value/versions` which will return header only and will show SSL certificate information.  Make sure you are trusting the Issuer